# can handlebars each loop access parent model id

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

If I have a model like this:

```
App.Group = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  persons : DS.hasMany('App.Person')
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr('string'),
  age : DS.attr('object'),
  group : DS.belongsTo('App.Group')
});
```

And if I have fixture data like this:

```
App.Group.FIXTURES = [{
 title : "Group A",
 persons : [10,12]
 },{
 title: "Group B",
 persons: [13,14]
}]

App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
 name: "Bill",
 age: 24
},{
 name: "Ted",
 age: 25
},{
 name: "Mr. Excellent",
 age: 30
},{
 name: "Mr. Adventures",
 age: 21
}]
```

And a template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="Group">
  {{title}}
  {{render person}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="Person">
  {{#each in controller}}
     {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

So what happens right now is the person template displays all the persons in the person array. How can I get the each loop to only go over the Persons in Group A, rather than displaying every Person in the fixture?  Can this be done in handlebars? Or is this something I need to specify in the route?

Comment: you should do this via ember controllers. not with handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second argument of the render helper to pass the model for the person controller...

```
{{render person persons}}
```

But your Person.FIXTURES and group.FIXTURES must have the ids for the relations

```
App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
  id:10,
  name: "Bill",
  age: 24
},
[...]
App.Group.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  title : "Group A",
  persons : [10,12]
},
[...]
```

Comment: boom perfect answer. Thanks a million :)